# Как понять принцип работы re?

Tags: python, re

Искал на интернет-ресурсах информацию о работе регулярных выражений и их синтаксису
Чтобы расширить кругозор в парсинге с помощью re.compile
Нашёл недостаточное количество информации чтобы понять простейший фильтр вики в учебнике
Можете ли помочь и объяснить что и за что отвечает?

```
re.compile("^(/wiki/)(?!:).)*$")
```

Я понял только что делает `^(/wiki/)` но дальше непонятно и так-же непонятно почему перед текстом не используеться `r`

Comment: «так-же непонятно почему перед текстом не используеться `r`» — а зачем он по вашему там нужен?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=введение+в+регулярные+выражения

Comment: `r` не признак строки регулярки. Он заставляет читать \ не как экранирующий символ, а как сам обратный слеш. В выражении нет обратного слеша и `r` не нужен.

Comment: Для освоения регулярок в сети много ресурсов, где наглядно "рисуется" соответствие элементов выражения и анализируемой строки.  Начинайте осваивать ргулярки не на Питоне, а на этих ресурсах. Когда надо минимально сложное выражение составить и отладить, я и сам к ним обращаюсь.

Comment: "Я понял только что делает ^(/wiki/)", а дальше  - если это не сопровождается, 0 или множеством смайликов до конца строки. Шутка.

Comment: Ну, вы взяли сложноватое выражение для начала. Начните лучше с азов, с простейших регулярных выражений. Когда их поймёте - тогда двигайтесь в сторону сложных.